# Encoding of a file via jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I was wondering if i can get the real encoding of a file uploaded in one of the steps of the jenkins pipelines.

Need : To verify if the file uploaded has ANSI encoding.

Already tried :

```
stage("Upload Script Majbase File dans TAR") {
         steps {
            unstash 'scriptMajbase'
            script {
               fileOperations([fileRenameOperation(destination: "${WORKSPACE}/scriptMajbase.txt", source: "scriptMajbase")])
         def file1 = readFile("${WORKSPACE}/scriptMajbase.txt")
        def filePath = "${WORKSPACE}/scriptMajbase.txt"
        /**def file = new File(filePath)
        def inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
        def reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream)
        def encoding = reader.getEncoding()**/
        
        
        sh 'ls /path/to/your/file && echo "File exists!" || echo "File does not exist."'
       /** if (encoding == "Cp1252") {
            echo "File encoding is ANSI."
        } else {
            echo "File encoding is not ANSI."
        }**/
         }
      }
      } 


OR 

stage('Check for existence of index.html') {
  steps {
    script {
      if (fileExists('src/main/resources/index.html')) {
        echo "File src/main/resources/index.html found!"
      }
    }
  }
}

OR 

def myFile = 'path/to/my/file.txt'
if (fileExists(myFile)) {
  sh "file -i ${myFile}" // outputs the encoding of the file
} else {
  echo "File not found: ${myFile}"
}
```

But i always get the following error
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: file for class: WorkflowScript

Comment: `echo "File is empty =>  ${file!=null}"` this line references `file` variable, but its declaration is commented out.

Comment: i removed the commented line

Comment: The `sh` approach (`sh "file -i ${myFile}"`), works, I thought the exception it's probably gone with the removed line of the snippet, as @Iterokun already notes in his comment.